# Issue with the adb shell on a tablet 20080411

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, fastboot

Hello i am trying to fastboot my tablet serialno 20080411 my problem is when i try to acces in the shell of the tablet that happens the problem, i try to make a ls the system said `/system/bin/sh: ls: not found` how i can fixed this problem?

Comment: Hidura, your question is a bit unclear: 1) the serialno of your tablet is not helpful -- brand and model would be better. 2) do you try the `ls` while in fastboot mode when you get that error, or in normal mode, or when?

Comment: I was trying the ls on fastboot mode

Comment: I thought so. Fastboot mode is very limited concerning available commands -- the only thing it is supposed to do is to receive basic commands from a connected computer (like wipe, unlock, flash, or boot from an image stored on the computer). It's not intended for full-fledged shell operations. Try those in normal mode, or while in recovery, and your `ls` will be available. // Guess I have to care for the [fastboot tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) to carry some more information :)